# displaying month name chronologically for graphs in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, altair

I am creating a chart in jupyter notebook which displays fire factors sorted by month. however it is sorting months alphabetically and not chronologically, the ways I've tried don't seem to have any effect on the graph. I'm super new to this so would appreciate any help! I've also attached a screenshot of what the graph look like. along the x axis you can see the months.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
data = pd.read_csv('forestfires.csv')

new_order = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']
data = data.reindex(new_order, axis=0)

alt.Chart(data).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('month:O',
          sort='ascending'), 
    alt.Y('FFMC:Q'),
    alt.Size('ISI:Q')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is arising with reinexing.
Don't reindex and it should resolve the issue.

```
data = data.set_index('new_order', inplace=True)
```

Comment: hmm now it says KeyError: "None of ['new_order'] are in the columns"

Comment: new_order is the column name or header which you have to set. like you mentioned title "months"

Answer (score 0):

oh I realised it can actually be done super simply:

alt.X('month:O',
title='months',
sort = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"]), ... etc